# GET Rest API using WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, webclient

Postman is returning only part of the information when calling.

```
[
{
    "cucoId": null,
    "externalId": "a75c41d3-bfcc-55b5-bda8-77670d01f081",
    "customers": null
}
```

]

For some reason the rest of the attributes are filled with null.

The POJO is as follows:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CuCoPerson {

    //@JsonProperty("cucoId")
    private Integer cucoId;

    //@JsonProperty("externalId")
    private String externalId;

    //@JsonProperty("customers")
    //@Valid
    private List<CustomerRelation> customers;
}
```

And the endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/getCucoId/{cucoId}")
    public Mono<CuCoPerson> getCucoRelationById(@PathVariable Integer cucoId, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("/getRelationByCucoId/" + cucoId)
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer eyJraWQiOi...")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CuCoPerson.class);
    }
```

UPDATE:

If I run in Postman I get this:

[image]

UPDATE 2:
The request in the Microservice which I'm trying to call is like this:

[image]

Any idea what's going on here??
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share response json from  you are getting from`"/getRelationByCucoId/" + cucoId`

Comment: Hi Alex! I'm getting this on Postman [
{
    "cucoId": null,
    "externalId": "a75c41d3-bfcc-55b5-bda8-77670d01f081",
    "customers": null
}
]

Comment: I mean response from the `webClient.get`

Comment: I dont see any response

Comment: With `webClient.get` you are trying to get response from external endpoint, so we just would like to make sure that response from external endpoint  matches your DTO  `CuCoPerson`

Comment: @DiegoMG you can't debug reactive code like this. Try to make request to the `"/getRelationByCucoId/" + cucoId ` endpoint using postman and share results

Comment: @Alex done! I've uploaded a pic.

Comment: @DiegoMG this is a response from your controller and I'm asking about response from the endpoint your WebClint is accessing

Comment: I've just put the response of the original endpoint which Im trying to reach

Comment: I see that at least `cucoId` is not correspond `cucoID`

Comment: And you are trying to get `customers` but target system has `relatedCustomers`

Comment: Man! Yeah, it was that! Didn't know that it had to be match 100%. Thanks!!

Comment: So, please rename in your DTO `CuCoPerson`: `cucoId` to `cucoID` and `customers` to `relatedCustomers`

Comment: YEs! Just did it and now I'm getting the proper response! Thank you so much!